# What total process, max active process and max children process?

Tags: nginx, centos7, php-fpm

```
pool:                 www
process manager:      dynamic
start time:           22/Oct/2017:15:32:05 -0400
start since:          60605
accepted conn:        5169879
listen queue:         0
max listen queue:     0
listen queue len:     0
idle processes:       33
active processes:     8
total processes:      41
max active processes: 107
max children reached: 0
slow requests:        0
```

What does total processes, max active processes and max children reached mean?
How can i understand the server load from these values? Which value (for example) indicate the connection is full?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In Nginx configurations, we can specify the maximum number of connections.
While please keep in mind that for each new connection, it will be an addition to the extra CPU and memory usage.

**Active processes:**

Nginx will use master and child processes to serve the user requests, depending upon the number of connections that we have configured, it will expand the number of processes.

**Server Load**

This will vary with the memory and the CPU of the system.

Please refer this for more information

https://www.nginx.com/blog/inside-nginx-how-we-designed-for-performance-scale/

Answer (score 2):

For example you have 23 fpm children running at moment (**total processes**). 10 of them are idle and not processing a php code. So 13 **active processes** left. **Active process** - a child processing a php code at moment. **Max active processes** - the maximum number of active processes since FPM has started. **Max children reached** - number of times, the process limit (you set it in php-fpm pool config as max_childre ) has been reached. If your **max children reached** > 0 you should investigate it.

https://easyengine.io/tutorials/php/fpm-status-page/

Comment: Thanks for the info. ps.max_children and start servers. what is the difference? Which one is actually process here?

Comment: I am getting `WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers)'